# Issues connecting to local Postgres - "Too many levels of symbolic links"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When attempting to open my Rails Console and making a Query, I receive the following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: Too many levels of symbolic links
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I've searched all over the web, but the only answers for this specific error I can find relate to Ubunut, any ideas what I can do ?

Comment: What do you get for `ls -ld /tmp` and `ls -ld /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`?

Comment: The error is usually caused by having a symbolic link that points to itself. This is a system configuration problem that almost certainly has nothing to do with Rails or even programming.